# Separate webcontent from WAR file on JBOSS 6

Tags: jboss, war

Is it possible to keep the webcontent separate from the WAR when deploying to JBOSS. The motivation for this is to avoid WAR deployment when there are JSP changes.

For example, we need to keep the jsps and other webcontent (css, images etc) in a folder like /home/jboss/webcontent/ and the server/application when referring to any JSPs/images etc needs pick and translate the jsp files from this location.

Thanks so much in advance.

Regards,
Vinay

Comment: AFAIK jboss redeploys WARs only when /WEB-INF/web.xml is updated or touched. May be you should check your IDE settings to not trigger redeploy with a change of JSPs?

Comment: #tair : My requirement is more to keep the JSPs out of the WAR because the front end and backend services are handled by 2 different teams and that makes deployment difficult if all of them are in one WAR...